# Change foreign key reference column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have one table called `Records` and one table called `Users`.

`Records` currently has a foreign key constraint for column `Users`.`Username` and I would like to change this to instead reference `Users`.`ID`.

My questions is how would one maintain the relationship between `Records` and `Users` while removing the `Users`.`Username` column?

This is for MySQL InnoDB.

Comment: 'My questions is how would one maintain the relationship between' - what is your concern here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to create a procedure to iterate through each row in the `Users` table and update a new `Records`.`user_id` column in the `Records` table that matched each `Users`.`Username`.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UPDATE_USERS;    
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_USERS()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Users` INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i < n DO
    UPDATE `Records` SET user_id=(SELECT id from `Users` LIMIT i,1) WHERE USERNAME=(SELECT USERNAME from `Users` LIMIT i,1);
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a foreign key mapping with Users.ID as well provided Users.Username is unique and has a one to one relationship with Users.ID. Once done, you can remove the constraint on Users.Username.